# Excess errors on model from somewhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, authlogic

I have a `User` model, and use an `acts_as_authentic` (from authlogic) on it. My `User` model have 3 validations on `username` and looks as following:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic

  validates_presence_of   :username    
  validates_length_of     :username, :within => 4..40 
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

end
```

I'm writing a test to see my validations in action. Somehow, I get 2 errors instead of one when validating a uniqueness of a name. To see excess error, I do the following test:

```
describe User do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.build(:user)
  end

  it "should have a username longer then 3 symbols" do
    @user2 = Factory(:user)
    @user.username = @user2.username
    @user.save

    puts @user.errors.inspect
  end
end
```

I got 2 errors on `username`: `@errors={"username"=>["has already been taken", "has already been taken"]}`.

Another case of problem is when I set username to `nil`. Somehow I get four validation errors instead of three: `@errors={"username"=>["is too short (minimum is 3 characters)", "should use only letters, numbers, spaces, and .-_@ please.", "can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 4 characters)"]}`

I think authlogic is one that causes this strange behaviour. But I can't even imagine on how to solve that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because authlogic has some build in validations and both them and your validations are run.

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=authlogic+default+validations+login) seems to give some answers to this topic. [This one](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37055) is for example for password field.